# Change and Input events

Tags: javascript, events

So I'm unable to register for change or input events that allow me to grab the data that was just changed and apply it somewhere else...

```
document.getElementById("fI").addEventListener("input", blabla);
function blabla() {
  var something = document.getElementById("fI").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("example2").innerHTML = something+" continue the rest of the script here";
}
```

This code doesn't execute and I can't figure out why from the documentation...

Edit:

This is the only HTML on the page, I'm debugging this right now

```
<textarea id="fI"></textarea>
<button type="button" id='pressMe'>Press Me</button>
<textarea id="example2"></textarea>
```

I've also used `<p>` for the recipient of the changed `innerHTML`

I've tested this code all on it's own, just like this, and it didn't work, however I'm trying to connect the code to this event listener too

```
document.getElementById("pressMe").addEventListener("click",doSomething);
function doSomething () {
  var something = prompt("Please enter something", "something");
  if (something !== null) {
    document.getElementById("fI").innerHTML = something;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do your elements exist in the DOM at the point at which you assign call `addEventListener()`? Do they both exist at all? Whereabouts is the `<script>`, in the document, in the `<head>` or somewhere in the `<body>`?

Comment: Post your HTML. The code you provided seems valid. The problem is in somewhere else in your code.

Comment: That's it, nothing else was on the page when I tested the code, I'll try again just for fun

Comment: So, it magically works now, but not with the additional code, I'm trying to prompt the user, get the value, and then add the value programmatically to an element, having an event listener wait for the elements value to change by the script to execute some more code.  So my edit will happen first, and then the input event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.value` to get/set the contents of a textarea element. You were using `.innerHTML`.

```js
document.getElementById("pressMe").addEventListener("click", doSomething);

function doSomething() {
    var something = prompt("Please enter something", "something");
    if (something !== null) {
        document.getElementById("fI").value = something;
    }
}

document.getElementById("fI").addEventListener("input", blabla);

function blabla() {
    var something = document.getElementById("fI").value;
    document.getElementById("example2").value = something;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="fI"></textarea>
<button type="button" id='pressMe'>Press Me</button>
<textarea id="example2"></textarea>
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either... it only executes the change listener after I manually change the value, not after the value is changed programmatically

Comment: @JacobEdward What exactly do you want to do? Try to be specific as much as you can.

Comment: Well, I wanted it to change on a programmatic injection, but nevermind, thanks for the help, btw, what was the thing about .value, the innerHTML works perfectly...

Comment: It needs to be triggered programmatically since I'm trying to set up an extension that gets updated after a script I have running on a website is updated from the server, not manually...

Comment: @JacobEdward I'm not sure I get what you're trying to say. You want to prompt the user, get the prompt value, enter it to `#fI`, and you also want `#example2` to have the same value as `#fI`?

Comment: This was a debugging script to try to add an event listener for an element so that another function would run once it was given input programmatically, right now, the event listener only runs when it's change is done manually, the reason why I need to assign the listener for a programmatic injection is because this is going to be used in a browser extension that doesn't have access to my websites programmatic injection (otherwise simply calling the other function after the injection would work), but still needs to listen for the injection to know when to fire.

Comment: No, it needs to be called via a separate execution stream since the event listener is going to be run through a separately from the prompt that updates the element programmatically.  I'm probably going to ask a new question since I wasn't completely clear with this one.

Comment: @JacobEdward [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uhhf1009/1/). If this doesn't work, I give up :)

Answer (score 0):

you are not retrieving the value of your `textarea` correctly. you should be using .value instead of .innerHTML

```
 var something = document.getElementById("fI").value;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6pL8qony/

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either... it only executes the change listener after I manually change the value, not after the value is changed programmatically

Comment: Did you look at the fiddle? That does change for me ... I added a comment as to where you had to add a function call if you wanted it to work "both ways"

Comment: this has nothing to do with the code, but you wouldn't happen to be a vegan would you?

Comment: Nevermind about the vegan thing, so that does what I want, but it doesn't do it by firing the change event after it was changed programmatically... I'm trying to think if that works though, I've been having issues with setTimeouts and prompts not waiting for the feedback, but this seems to be working now even if it didn't do that before...  do you know if there are special quirks to know about prompts?

Comment: I don't really use prompts but it seems to be fine ... The fiddle thing worked even on my phone ;) - and I want to understand the vegan question

Comment: Oh, lol I felt compelled to look at your photo and ask you if you were Vegan, I'm Vegan so that might make it seem less bizarrely random

Comment: Lol - I don't think I ate meat before that pic was taken ... ;)

Comment: As in you were a Vegan before the picture was taken?  Lol I'm confused... either way, we should move the vegan discussion to facebook or something before an admin starts yelling

Comment: This was a debugging script to try to add an event listener for an element so that another function would run once it was given input programmatically, right now, the event listener only runs when it's change is done manually, the reason why I need to assign the listener for a programmatic injection is because this is going to be used in a browser extension that doesn't have access to my websites programmatic injection (otherwise simply calling the other function after the injection would work), but still needs to listen for the injection to know when to fire.

Comment: if you find a way to bind it with an eventListener let me know! i think you'll end up doing a very hacky workaround using setIntervals or you could manually trigger the change event which under your circumstances would be the cleanest solution: document.getElementById("fI").dispatchEvent(new Event("input")); -> this means you don't really need to have any more knowledge of the code that is tied to it - you are just dispatching an event. - http://jsfiddle.net/6pL8qony/1/